# Remove package sources from cabal directory

Tags: haskell, cabal

Having installed a few packages with a large number of dependencies via cabal install, I now have several hundred megabytes of source files in my ~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org directory. As I'm trying to work on a small SSD, space is at a premium for me. Can I safely remove these, or will doing so cause failures later on?

Comment: the biggest problem you can get into is that you'll have to redownload them or that you mess up your repo - but it's a not easy to tell from afar - also I would strongly recommend going with stack in the future (although it probably will not save you space as long as you did not use sandboxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org` won't cause any failure, but cabal-install will redownload the huge `00-index.tar` next time when you try compiling something and this single file is 80+% the size of the folder. It's the index of the whole haskell universe, now around 200MB and hopefully will grow without bound in future.

Compiled libraries and executables won't be affected, so if you are not going to build anything more it's fine to remove the whole folder.